# angular 6 show preloader for each component except one

Tags: angular

So, I have this **Spinner** component declared, which is just a simple preloader CSS graphic.
It sits on my **App** component and checks to see if we are loading any htpp data.
If we are, it shows the spinner. If we are not, then it hides the spinner:

```
<div class="spinner-container" *ngIf="loading">
  <div class="spinner">
    <div class="bounce1"></div>
    <div class="bounce2"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I now have a situation where we don't want to show the spinner at all when on a certain component.
I did try to do this using urls:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { SpinnerService } from '../services/spinner.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pyb-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loading: boolean;

  private widgetUrls: any[] = ['scenarios', 'questions', 'answers', 'results']
  private url: string

  private routeSubscription: Subscription
  private spinnerSubscription: Subscription

  constructor(
    private route: Router,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.events.subscribe(event => this.getCurrentUrl(event));
    this.spinnerSubscription = this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged.subscribe(loading => this.showSpinner(loading));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.routeSubscription) this.routeSubscription.unsubscribe();
    if (this.spinnerSubscription) this.spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  private showSpinner(loading: boolean) {
    if (this.url) {
      let urlSegments = this.url.split('/');
      if (urlSegments.length > 1) {
        let lastSegment = urlSegments[urlSegments.length - 1];
        let index = this.widgetUrls.indexOf(lastSegment);

        if (index > -1) {
          this.loading = false;
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    this.loading = loading;
  }

  private getCurrentUrl(event: any) {
    if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
      this.url = event.url;
    }
  }
}
```

But in my case, this won't work because my component has it's routes like this:

```
const widgetRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':category', redirectTo: ':category/scenarios', pathMatch: 'full', data: { state: 'widget' } },
  { path: ':category/:path', component: WidgetComponent, data: { state: 'widget' } }
];
```

So you can go to `/cameras` for example and it will show my preloader, but I don't want it to.
I could put an exemption in my **SpinnerComponent** for each and every category, but that seems crazy.

What I would like to do is check the name of the component that is resolved when a route changes and then hide the preloader if it matches my component.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property "data" to add a property "noSpinner" to all the routes you don't need spinner

```
{ path: ':category/:path', 
  component: WidgetComponent, 
  data: { state: 'widget',noSpinner:true } 
}
```

If you subscribe to activatedRoute.data, you get the value, If !res.noSpinner, subscribe to onLoadingChange

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res)
     if (!res.noSpinner)
          this.spinnerSubscription = this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged
            .subscribe(loading => this.showSpinner(loading));
    })
```

Well, really you can use switchMap to get only one subscription

```
this.spinnerSubscription = this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
     switchMap(res=>{
       console.log(res)
       if (!res.noSpinner)
          return this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged
       else 
          return of(false);
     }))
     .subscribe(loading => this.showSpinner(loading));
```

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work; can you edit your answer to show a complete example please? The `activatedRoute` never seems to change

Answer (score 0):

I am going to expand on Eliseo's answer. He was right in what he was saying, but it was only a partial answer.
The actual answer was to change my **ngOnInit** to this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.spinnerSubscription = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.activatedRoute),
      map(route => route.firstChild),
      switchMap(route => route.data),
      switchMap(data => {
        if (!data.disableSpinner)
          return this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged
        else 
          return of(false);
      })
    ).subscribe(loading => this.loading = loading);
}
```

Once this was done, I could use the data in my routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' }, // Put first so it redirects :)
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { state: 'home' } },

  // Lazy load
  { path: '', loadChildren: './widget/widget.module#WidgetModule', data: { state: 'widget', disableSpinner: true } }, // Put this last as it has empty path

  // 404
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }, // 404?
]
```

One thing to note here; if you are using **lazy loading**, you **must** make sure the data object is part of the initial declaration.
I did have my `data` object declared in my **widget routing module** but it was being ignored.

I hope this helps someone else.

PS: To make sure this can actually help someone else; here is my entire component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription, of } from 'rxjs';

import { SpinnerService } from '../services/spinner.service';
import { switchMap, filter, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'pyb-spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  loading: boolean;

  private spinnerSubscription: Subscription

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinnerSubscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        map(() => this.activatedRoute),
        map(route => route.firstChild),
        switchMap(route => route.data),
        switchMap(data => {   
          if (!data.disableSpinner)
            return this.spinnerService.onLoadingChanged
          else 
            return of(false);
        })
      ).subscribe(loading => this.loading = loading);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.spinnerSubscription) this.spinnerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```